# 176. Second Highest Salary

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select salary 
from employee
order by salary desc limit 2 
having salary <> max(salary)

select salary 
from employee 
order by salary desc limit 1 
having salary not in (select max(salary) from employee);
```

The above-stated query is not working and giving a response as

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'having salary <> max(salary)' at line 2

As having is used for aggregator functions this should work IMO.

Please help me out by explaining why it is not working also I am trying to learn SQL query please provide me with a resource if possible.

Comment: HAVING comes before ORDER BY. However, you're going in the wrong direction with HAVING.

Comment: Per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html, `HAVING` needs to follow `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hint: MySQL `LIMIT` also has an optional _offset_ argument.

Comment: _As having is used for aggregator functions this should work IMO._ Where is your agregator function?

Comment: `SELECT salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hello Sir, I have used max for the aggregator function.

Comment: But not in the first query, and in the second its in the subquery :)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Comment: With these three salaries, which one do you consider second highest: 5000, 5000, 3000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is using window function :

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary Desc) AS Rnk
FROM employee
)
SELECT cte.salary
FROM cte
WHERE Rnk=2;
```

Note if you have salaries  `5000, 5000, 3000` , as @Thorsten Kettner mentioned in the comment, the second highest salary would be 3000.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90c67881bcf6fd8f0c50a5a351f6b9ca

Comment: ... and with 5000, 5000, 3000, 3000, you'd select it twice :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner not if `SELECT distinct cte.salary` is applied

Answer (score 0):

We want the second highest salary.

```
<!-- -->
>     create table employee (salary int);
>     insert into employee values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);
> 
> <pre>
> ✓
> 
> ✓
> </pre>

<!-- -->
>       select salary 
>       from employee 
>       order by salary desc 
>       limit 1, 1 ;
> 
> <pre>
> | salary |
> | -----: |
> |      7 |
> </pre>

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddf303748ee5620b2334b95621024840)*
```

Comment: Hint: MySQL `LIMIT` also has an optional _offset_ argument.

Comment: Somewhat overkill I would suggest

Comment: Ooo thats a bit of a change...... for the better